# Pop up window from menu overflow item selected android

Tags: android, popupwindow

I am trying to display a pop up window when i click on a menu overflow item. I have written some code also for that. But it outputs nothing.

Here is some code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.settings_id: 
        displayPopupWindow();
        return true;

    case R.id.about_us_id:

        return true;

        case R.id.logout_id:
        startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this,MainActivity.class));
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } 
}

public void displayPopupWindow() {
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(this);
View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
popup.setContentView(layout);
popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popup.setFocusable(true);
popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

}
```

My Xml file Code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    tools:text="This is a Pop Up Window!"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Where is the error? Please help me.

Comment: its working for me. can you please change code something like this and try ?

Comment: View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(layout, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: I want to show my popup.xml file. But I am not able to show by using your code :( It is only showing a simple layout and textview

Comment: it will show, the file you mentioned in R.layout.popup. Which one is your popup layout ?

Comment: I have written the xml code of my popup layout in my question

Comment: you said in above comments that "showing a simple layout and textview". And that's what you xml has.

Comment: also, in your popup xml, change the RelativeLayout's layout_width and height to wrap_content.

Comment: it's not working!!

Comment: View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(layout, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        popup.setContentView(layout);
        popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popup.setFocusable(true);
        popup.showAtLocation(layout,Gravity.CENTER, 50, -30);

Comment: it remains same

Comment: can you check once again whether your id of option menu item is "settings_id" in menu xml ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution,

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private PopupWindow mPopupWindow;
    private Button btnClosePopup;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.items, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.phone:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.computer:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Computer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.gamepad:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Gamepad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.camera:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                initiatePopupWindow();
                break;

            case R.id.video:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.email:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected EMail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }
        return true;

    }

    private void initiatePopupWindow() {
        try {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
            mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 370, true);
            mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

            btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
            btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mPopupWindow.dismiss();

                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**popup.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_element"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#444444"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10sp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:text="Hello!" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_close_popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Close" />

</LinearLayout>
```